# How to add multiple URL to one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I using Next.js

I have this structure:

[image]

I need to open the same component for each URLs, like this 'http://localhost:3000/hakkimizda', 'http://localhost:3000/cerez-politikasi', 'http://localhost:3000/kullanim-kosullari'
This component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

class InfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="info-page">
            <div className="info-page__header">
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(InfoPage));
```

How can I open the same component in several different URLs in Next.js?

Comment: You can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites).

Comment: Or [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

Comment: or [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your page a component and render that component in all these pages:

- `components/Shared.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

class InfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="info-page">
            <div className="info-page__header">
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(InfoPage));
```

- `pages/hakkimizda.js`
- `pages/cerez-politikasi.js`
- `pages/kullanim-kosullari.js`

```
import React from 'react`;
import Shared from '../components/Shared/';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Shared />
  );
}
```

Comment: I know that
How can create just one file to URLs ?
not 3 (pages/hakkimizda.js, pages/cerez-politikasi.js, pages/kullanim-kosullari.js )

Comment: As @98sean98 suggested earlier, you'll want [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) for that.